# how to install my app on Motorola Android

Tags: android, installation, motorola

I'd like to install my app on Motorola Android as a testing. how to? Please share me any step by step link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up assuming you are using the eclipse plugin. Might be better just to read them yourself.

```
* Declare your application as debuggable in your manifest
```

In Eclipse, you can do this from the Application tab when viewing the Manifest (on the right side, set Debuggable to true). Otherwise, in the AndroidManifest.xml  file, add android:debuggable="true" to the   element.

```
* Enable USB Debugging on your device
```

On the device, go to the home screen, press MENU, select Applications  > Development, then enable USB debugging.

```
* Ensure that your development computer can detect your device when connected via USB
```

Once set up and your device is connected via USB, install your application on the device by selecting Run > Run (or Run > Debug) from the Eclipse menu bar.

Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

You can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from your SDK tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the device name listed as a "device."

If using Eclipse, run or debug as usual. You will be presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you want to install and run the application.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I think you answer is also useful for debugging with Android Device. For the installation, I did it by reading this link - http://www.careace.net/2010/05/12/how-to-install-non-market-apk-application-on-an-android-phone/comment-page-1/

Comment: @roman this answer is not COMPLETELY correct.  this does NOT apply to MOTOROLA devices, for which you need to install MOTODEV or run ADB DEVICES from terminal (linux).  many motorola devices show up as "??????????" when trying to debug "directly" from eclipse without adb devices first.