# can't get ADB to recognize my galaxy

Tags: android, adb

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895531/how-to-install-my-app-on-motorola-android) post trying to run my application on my galaxy. My app is debuggable, USB debugging is checked on phone and I've manually installed USB drivers - my device manager shows me that I have Android ADB Interface installed. 
Despite it all - when I am running adb devices it would only list the emulator.
Any ideas? thanks!

P.s. I am running windows 7 and the mobile is Samsung Galaxi 1900I

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848567/adb-samsung-galaxy

Comment: [Here's the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-device)

Answer (score 0):

I use Droid X, in Win 7.
sometimes it is not work too (adb can't detect my device)
but the solutions is simple, just switch usb connection into Windows Media Sync (ie. from PC Mode) , it is work for me.

also make sure to set your device in Debug mode (USB Debugging)

Comment: my device is in debug mode, but i didn't understand what you wrote before. switching my usb into windows media sync? what is it, what does it meen? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yotamoo, When you first plug in, Windows offers you some choices on how to deal with the new device; Open in File Explorer, etc...one of them is Windows Media Player. Choose that. I had similar problems and this solution worked for me and my galaxy S3...

hakim, why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you installed the USB Drivers.
2. Locate your phone in Device Manager and see if it working correctly.
   These are the correct [drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows).
3. Turn Debugging mode on on your phone.
4. You will be prompted to accept USB debugging on your device if it detects some application would like to use it.
5. After you agree it will pop up as a debug-able device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems.

Try to update your smartphone in the device manager (computer->properties).
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7